# How to scan a string using scanf with C++

Tags: c++

I have tried most of the string and char format types and they are not working and I have no Idea why. Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    string string2;
    string string;

    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    printf("Hi my name is Josh %s\n",string2);
    scanf("%s",&string);
    printf("hi %s",string);
}
```

Comment: `scanf`'s `%s` format specifier requires a matching character array parameter, not a `std::string`.

Comment: Mixing of C and CPP style is not good idea in general. As it is mentioned already you should std::cin. If you are reading a string like 'Josh Surname' you may consider cin.getline().

If you really want to use scanf then consider sscanf instead.

Comment: Use `std::getline(std::cin, string2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're showing (`scanf("%s",&string);`) doesn't work (and never could, by e.g. giving different format specifiers)!

`scanf()` used with the `%s` format specifier requires a corresponding `char*` pointer referencing a raw `char[]` array to receive the read data in the parameter list. The `std::string` pointer you're passing in your example, doesn't provide automatic casting to the referred `std::string` instances internally managed `char[]` buffer that way though.

You could try to use [`&string.front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) instead, but I wouldn't really recommend that, unless you're very sure what you're doing.

For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you should better use `std::cin` and
`std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const std::string&)`
instead:

```
std::cout << "Put in string value:" << std::endl;
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

<sub>([xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) isn't relevant for your question BTW!)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix `std::cout` with `::printf`. Prefer to use the [C++ Standard IO library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) over C functions from `stdio`.

Your code should look a little like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string string2;
    std::string other_string;

    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    std::cout << "Hi my name is Josh " <<  string2 << '\n';
    std::cin >> other_string;
    std::cout << "hi " << other_string;
}
```